# Hitting url in addressbar submits get method instead of post

Tags: java, url, get, http-post

I have a form with POST method. if i click on submit button it submits as POST and even if i reload the page its working fine but weird thing is when i click in address bar and hit enter it submits as GET instead of POST. I am not able to understand this behaviour
Browser - Chrome.
server - tomcat 7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is generally how browsers work.  Anything in the address bar is treated as a GET request.

Comment: It is the normal and desired behavior in all of the browsers. Note that when you reload a POST request, the browser warns you before reloading. That is because GET is idempotent (it is expected not to change the resource) while POST is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. Posts go in the header and gets go on the url.

There is no way I know of to post by entering data in the url bar.

Choose how you want to submit and stick with it. If you want to submit from the address bar you will have to use the get method.